# Trying to create & then expand a table with m code in power query

Tags: powerquery, m

I am using power query m language. I have created a blank query & written this code

```
let
    Source =  #table(                
                {"first", "second"},
                {
                    {Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Table.FromRecords({[order_id = "a_01", place = "america", price = 700]}), "first", {"order_id", "place", "price"}), "dd"}
                }
              )
in
    Source
```

Actually I am trying to create a table with code & immediately trying to expand it within first column. But it's showing following error
Expression.Error: The column 'first' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    first

I cannot figure out the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
let
Source =  #table(                
            {"first", "second"},
            {
               {Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Table.FromRecords({[first = [order_id = "a_01", place = "america", price = 700]]}), "first", {"order_id", "place", "price"}), "dd"}
            }
          ),
#"Expanded first" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "first", {"order_id", "place", "price"}, {"order_id", "place", "price"})
in
#"Expanded first"
```

It gives this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`first` is not a column the table you passed into `Table.ExpandRecordColumn`. Those columns are `order_id`, `place`, and `price`. If you want to expand the `first` column in the table you made with `#table`, you need to use `Table.ExpandTableColumn` and it needs to use the table made with `#table` as its first parameter.